# How to support date format internationalization XSL for PDF output

Tags: xml, date, xslt, pdf, internationalization

So my input is date/time like this:

```
2014-03-11T14:50:12-05:00
```

I am trying to get output in format like this:

```
March 11, 2014, 14:50:12
```

I do not have much experience with internationalization and XSL.
Currently I have template that parses this and if 1 outputs January, if 2 Feb...
But that is not the best solution as it required translation file for months.

Fairly sure there must be a better way to do this without reinventing the wheel.

I am using XSLT 1.0 and Apache FOP for creating PDF.

The way I know what language it needs to be in is parameter. It is passed to xsl as in example above param def

```
  <!-- Example: fop.bat ... -param outLang "en_US" -->
  <xsl:param name="outLang" select="'en_US'"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a very big difference here between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0; which version does your processor support? I am also not sure where does "nternationalization" come into this. The format you show is very much locale-specific.

Comment: Internationalization is supporting different locales.. not sure how you do not see internationalization. PDF will be in different language based on system locale so date format should be in that language

Comment: So how will your stylesheet know what the required locale is? Will it be the locale of the system that performs the transformation? That's going to be very difficult using XSLT 1.0 only. Which processor specifically will you be using?

Comment: This question is very broad and unclear - and on top of that it lacks basic information to reproduce a problem (e.g. XML input, your XSLT stylesheet, the _XSL-FO_ output you expect, where the information on the language comes from...).

Comment: I am using as stated in question Apache FOP.
I am calling fop.bat script with language parameter.
so I have parameter in xml that I pass on to the xsl.

I will update question with that info. 
@MathiasMüller input is given and expected output so not sure what do you mean

Comment: @MathiasMüller and how is it broad? I am asking how to handle date formatting from given xml input to generate output that I have given in language specified from parameter

Comment: Thanks for explaining where you get the lang information from. To respond to your other comments: You transform an input XML to XSL-FO, using an XSLT stylesheet, and finally use the XSL-FO output to generate PDF. We can only give sensible answers if you _show_ some code, not just strings.

Comment: I am afraid you have a very large wheel to invent in front of you, because none of this is provided for in XSLT 1.0 (and AFAIK, not much of it is implemented in XSLT 2.0 either). You will need to write a template for each expected language code (or one giant template with branching for each such code), and specify what you need to be done to the given date in terms of the order of the elements, separators to use, the names of months to use and the time format.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i was afraid that was the case... 
thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT Date Formating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868423/xslt-date-formating)