# XSLT Date Formatting

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xpath

I have had a look at various suggestions on here but none really help my problem.
Due to the sources my XML comes from i can receive dates in the following three formats;

```
04-04-2014(DD-MM-YYYY)
04-Apr-2014(DD-MMM-YYYY)
2014-04-04(YYYY-MM-DD)
```

I would like to have a function or simple command that will change all of these (other than the third, yet able to recognize that the third is correct) into YYYY-MM-DD

I have a long winded When/when/when to do this currently, but there must be an easier way. My current XSLT does the following;

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Jan')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-01-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Feb')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-02-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Mar')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-03-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Apr')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-04-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'May')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-05-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Jun')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-06-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Jul')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-07-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Aug')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-08-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Sep')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-09-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Oct')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-10-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Nov')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-11-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(date, 'Dec')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,6),'-12-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($dateStart) = 2">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,7),'-',substring(date,4,2),'-',substring(date,1,2))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So this will check if the date contains any months as JAN,Feb etc. and then if not, check if the first number up to - is 2 characters (DD) and format, other wise it assumes it is YYYY-MM-DD already and outputs it as it is.

I have tried - `<xsl:value-of select = "format-dateTime(date, '[Y0001]-[MN]-[D01]')"/>`
But this complains that the Dates year is not long enough (as date is being treated as a datetime, which should be in format YYYY-MM-DD

Thanks to Ian roberts Answer below, i created the below to deal with a few more scenarios and group the outputs together;

```
<xsl:variable name="months" select="('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')" />
<xsl:analyze-string select="date" flags="x"
       regex="^(
            (\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)
          | (\d\d)-([A-Za-z]{{3}})-(\d\d\d\d)
          | (\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)
          | (\d\d\d\d)-([A-Za-z]{{3}})-(\d\d)
          | (\d\d)([A-Za-z]{{3}})(\d\d\d\d)
          | (\d\d\d\d)([A-Za-z]{{3}})(\d\d))$">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(4)) then concat(regex-group(4),'-',regex-group(3),'-',regex-group(2)) else ''"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(7)) then concat(regex-group(7),'-',format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(6)), '00'),'-',regex-group(5)) else ''"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(8)) then concat(regex-group(8),'-',regex-group(9),'-',regex-group(10)) else ''"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(11)) then concat(regex-group(11),'-',format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(12)), '00'),'-',regex-group(13)) else ''"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(16)) then concat(regex-group(16),'-',format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(15)), '00'),'-',regex-group(14)) else ''"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(17)) then concat(regex-group(17),'-',format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(18)), '00'),'-',regex-group(19)) else ''"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you refer to `format-dateTime` you must be in XSLT 2.0, so you could approach it using regular expressions.  If you know you'll always have one of these three forms then you could use `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:variable name="months" select="('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', ...)" />

<xsl:analyze-string select="date" flags="x"
   regex="^(
        (\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)
      | (\d\d)-([A-Za-z]{{3}})-(\d\d\d\d)
      | (\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d))$">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <!-- year -->
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(7)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(8)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <!-- month -->
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (regex-group(6))
          then format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(6)), '00')
          else ''"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(9)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <!-- day -->
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(5)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(10)"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>

</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Each of your example formats will match exactly one of the three alternatives in the pattern, and all the `regex-group` calls for the non-matching alternatives will produce empty strings.

Comment: This regex uses (?: which is allowed in XSLT 3.0 but not XSLT 2.0

Comment: @MichaelKay I've replaced the non-capturing group with a normal one (and fixed up the group numbers to match).

Comment: Modified this a little just to defensively deal with a few more scenarios. and also grouping the selections together. edited original post.

Answer (score 3):

Even in XSLT 1.0, the problem becomes fairly trivial once you focus on the **structure** of the different formats rather than on their **contents**:

```
<xsl:template name="normalize-datestring">
<xsl:param name="datestring"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-before($datestring, '-')) = 4">
            <!-- this is YYYY-MM-DD; copy as is -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$datestring" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($datestring) = 10">
            <!-- this is DD-MM-YYYY; reorder -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestring, 7, 4)" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestring, 4, 2)" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestring, 1, 2)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- this is DD-MMM-YYYY; reorder and calculate month number-->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestring, 8, 4)" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring($datestring, 4, 3)" />
                <xsl:variable name="m" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1" />
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '00')" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestring, 1, 2)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function uitlizing similar regex and month sequence as the other answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f="function" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:variable name="d1" select="'2014-04-04'"/>
<xsl:variable name="d2" select="'04-04-2014'"/>
<xsl:variable name="d3" select="'04-Apr-2014'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="f:processDate($d2,'[Y0001]-[MN]-[D01]')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:processDate">
    <xsl:param name="dateString"/>
    <xsl:param name="datePattern"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month"
        select="('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- this will work for d1 -->
        <xsl:when test="$dateString castable as xs:date">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date( xs:date($dateString),$datePattern)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- d2 -->
        <xsl:when test="matches($dateString,'^(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d)$')">
            <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($dateString,1,2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($dateString,4,2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($dateString,7,4)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date( xs:date( string-join(($y, $m, $d), '-')), $datePattern )"
            />
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- d3 -->
        <xsl:when test="some $i in $month satisfies matches($dateString,concat('^(\d\d-',$i,'-\d\d\d\d)$'))">
            <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($dateString,1,2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="m"
                select="format-number(index-of($month,substring($dateString,4,3)),'00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($dateString,8,4)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date( xs:date( string-join(($y, $m, $d), '-')), $datePattern )"
            />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message>Unsupported dateString: <xsl:value-of select="$dateString"/></xsl:message>
            <xsl:value-of select="$dateString"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```